# About Python capwords

Tags: python, string, capitalize

```
from string import capwords

capwords('\"this is test\", please tell me.')
# output: '\"this Is Test\", Please Tell Me.'
             ^
```

Why is it not equal to this? ↓

```
'\"This Is Test\", Please Tell Me.'
   ^
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The `string` module is a leftover from Python 1 and was made almost entirely obsolete when Python 2.0 introduced string methods. You almost *never* need to `import string`. I can think of only two exceptions: `maketrans()` (which I have used now and then) and the locale-dependent uppercase/lowercase stuff (which I have never used).

Comment: Thanks guys. Using `.title()` solved the problem.

Comment: There's nothing obsolete about the `string` module. Some functions were deprecated in Python 2 in favor of methods on `str`. Those are gone in Python 3, so using the `string` module has nothing to do with those. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#helper-functions) for `string.capwords()` says:

> Split the argument into words using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), capitalize each word using [`str.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize), and join the capitalized words using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). If the optional second argument *sep* is absent or `None`, runs of whitespace characters are replaced by a single space and leading and trailing whitespace are removed, otherwise *sep* is used to split and join the words.

If we do this step by step:

```
>>> s = '\"this is test\", please tell me.'
>>> split = s.split()
>>> split
['"this', 'is', 'test",', 'please', 'tell', 'me.']
>>> ' '.join(x.capitalize() for x in split)
'"this Is Test", Please Tell Me.'
```

So you can see the double quotes are treated as being the part of the words, and so the following `"t"`s are not capitalised.

The [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method of strings is what you should use:

```
>>> s.title()
'"This Is Test", Please Tell Me.'
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing :-D

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because it is naive and is confused by the leading `"` which makes it think that `"This` does not begin with a letter.

Use the built-in string method `.title()` instead.

```
>>> '\"this is test\", please tell me.'.title()
'"This Is Test", Please Tell Me.'
```

This probably is the reason why `capwords()` remains in the `string` module but was never made a string method.

Comment: It turns out [string.capwords](https://docs.python.org/release/2.1/lib/module-string.html) has been a builtin forever, since 2.x. Rarely used.

Comment: useful but will be fail where you do not wish to capitalise e.g. 123abc -> 123Abc.

Comment: Capitalization is about text, not about arbitrary strings. To work with those you need to write a function that does what you want.